# Accessing static variables from Class object

Tags: java, arrays, class, casting, subclass

I currently have an array of type Class which holds only sub-classes of type BuildingComplex. It basically holds all of the different classes that are allowed to be constructed for game I am creating.

```
private static Class[] AVAILABLE = new Class[]{
   LumberCamp.class, Farm.class, Storehouse.class, Port.class, Barracks.class, Edifice.class
};
```

When I want to access a static variable from one of these classes (all which have this static variable due to inheritance from BuildingComplex), I cannot determine how to have AVAILABLE[i] access static variables because I cannot find any resource that will cast Class to a specific class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: static variables aren't available through inheritance.  if BuildingComplex has a static variable, then just access it via `BuildingComplex.STATIC_VAR`.

Comment: MY BAD! protected variables! AVAILABLE is static for the current class in use! My main problem would be accessing the class so that it is referenced as a subclass of BuildingComplex.

Comment: After reading the questing twice, I'm still not clear what you want. I imagine I'm not the only one. Try to be more concise and you might get a better answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good design, but check if `Class.asSubclass` does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if i completely understand your question, but are you looking for something like this?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Class<? extends BuildingComplex>[] AVAILABLE = new Class<? extends BuildingComplex>[]{
   LumberCamp.class, Farm.class, Storehouse.class, Port.class, Barracks.class, Edifice.class
};
```

Comment: Already tried this and it does not work. Cannot create generic Array of Class<? extends BuildingComplex>

Comment: yes, you need to add a SuppressWarnings annotation to get rid of that (due to the limitations of java arrays).  in this case, the code is completely safe.

Comment: I solved my problem by doing something very similar to this. Thank you!